# Kubernetes multiple secrets

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to mount several secrets in the same secret-volume for a kubernetes pod blueprint, but it's not accepted.

Tried and can't be created :

```
"spec": {
        "volumes": [
            {
              "name": "secret-volume",
              "secret": [
                  { "secretName": "secret1" },
                  { "secretName": "secret2" },
                  { "secretName": "secret3" }
              ]
            }
```

Like this it will just override them:

```
"volumes": [
   {
    "name": "secret-volume",
       "secret": { "secretName": "secret1" },
       "secret": { "secretName": "secret2" },
       "secret": { "secretName": "secret3" }
   }
]
```

Is there any way to mount a list of secrets in the same volume ?
Or only 1 secret / volume at the moment?

Thanks

Comment: You can try k8s projected volumes.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079318/how-to-mount-multiple-files-secrets-into-common-directory-in-kubernetes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Only one secret is allowed per secret volume

Comment: That's what I found out later by checking the src, but I hoped that I could use more then 1.

Comment: not sure if this helps, but a single secret can contain multiple files (its data field is a map of names to values)

Comment: I knew that I could "package" multiple files, but the problem was that 1 group of users could add 1 file as a secret, while another could add a different file as a secret, so it was easier to link those 2 secrets in 1 secret-volume :)