# How to mount multiple files / secrets into common directory in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I've multiple secrets created from different files. I'd like to store all of them in common directory `/var/secrets/`. Unfortunately, I'm unable to do that because kubernetes throws **'Invalid value: "/var/secret": must be unique** error during pod validation step. Below is an example of my pod definition.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: alpine-secret
  name: alpine-secret
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "3600"
    image: alpine
    name: alpine-secret
    volumeMounts:
    - name: xfile
      mountPath: "/var/secrets/"
      readOnly: true
    - name: yfile
      mountPath: "/var/secrets/"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: xfile
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret-one
  - name: yfile
    secret:
      secretName: my-secret-two
```

How can I store files from multiple secrets in the same directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:** 
@Jonas answer is correct!

However, if you use volumes as I did in the question then, short answer is **you cannot do that**, You have to specify `mountPath` to an unused directory - volumes have to be unique and cannot be mounted to common directory.

**Solution:**
What I did at the end was, instead keeping files in separate secrets, I created one secret with multiple files.

Comment: You can do subPath projections in a shared folder, but it would quickly get more complicated than it is worth.

Comment: Where does it say that it cannot be mounted to common directory?  Is it related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74779468/how-to-project-kubernetes-secret-at-the-etc-level)?

Comment: If his answer is correct, then mark the answer as correct and give the guy the credit xD

Answer (score 80):

### Projected Volume

You can use a [projected volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-projected-volume-storage/) to have two secrets in the same directory

**Example**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: alpine-secret
  name: alpine-secret
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - sleep
    - "3600"
    image: alpine
    name: alpine-secret
    volumeMounts:
    - name: xyfiles
      mountPath: "/var/secrets/"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: xyfiles
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: my-secret-one
      - secret:
          name: my-secret-two
```

Comment: With Openshift I could see all files under the path in the pod's terminal. However, the UI shows the volume is empty.

Answer (score 7):

(EDIT: Never mind - I just noticed @Jonas gave the same answer earlier. +1 from me)

Starting with Kubernetes v1.11+ it is possible with [`projected`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected) volumes:

> A projected volume maps several existing volume sources into the same
>   directory.
>
> Currently, the following types of volume sources can be projected:
>
> - secret
> - downwardAPI
> - configMap
> - serviceAccountToken

[This is an example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-projected-volume-storage/) for "... how to use a projected Volume to mount several existing volume sources into the same directory".

Answer (score 2):

May be subPath ([using subPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)) will help.

Example:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - name: app-redis-vol
          mountPath: /app/config/redis.yaml
          subPath: redis.yaml
        - name: app-config-vol
          mountPath: /app/config/app.yaml
          subPath: app.yaml
      volumes:
        - name: app-redis-vol
          configMap:
            name: config-map-redis
            items:
              - key: yourKey
                path: redis.yaml
        - name: app-config-vol
          configMap:
            name: config-map-app
            items:
              - key: yourKey
                path: app.yaml
```

Here your configMap named `config-map-redis` created from file `redis.yaml` mounted in `app/config/` as file `redis.yaml`.
Also configMap `config-map-app` mounted in `app/config/` as `app.yaml`

There is nice article about this here: [Injecting multiple Kubernetes volumes to the same directory](https://blog.sebastian-daschner.com/entries/multiple-kubernetes-volumes-directory)