# How to project Kubernetes secret at the /etc/ level?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I am following Kubernetes documentations on [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).  I have this `secret.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
type: Opaque
data:
  val1: YXNkZgo=
stringData:
  val1: asdf
```

and `secret-pod.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysecretpod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myval
      mountPath: /etc/secret
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: val1
      items:
      - key: val1
        path: myval
```

I use `kubectl apply -f` on both of these files.  Then using `kubectl exec -it mysecretpod -- cat /etc/secret/myval`, I can see the value `asdf` in the file `/etc/secret/myval` of `mysecretpod`.

However I want the mounted path to be `/etc/myval`.  Thus I make the following change in `secret-pod.yaml`:

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myval
      mountPath: /etc
      readOnly: true
```

After using `kubectl apply -f` on that file again, I check pod creation with `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`.  This is what I see:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS      AGE
default       mysecretpod                        0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   2 (34s ago)   62s
```

Looking into that pod using `kubectl describe pods mysecretpod`, this is what I see:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  35s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/mysecretpod to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     32s               kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 2.635766453s
  Warning  Failed     31s               kubelet            Error: failed to start container "mypod": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/c84a8d278dc2f131daf9f322d26ff8c54d68cea8cd9c0ce209f68d7a9b677b3c/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf" caused: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/4aaf54c61f7c80937a8edc094b27d6590538632e0209165e0b8c96e9e779a4b6/merged/etc/resolv.conf: read-only file system: unknown
  Normal   Pulled     28s               kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 3.313846185s
  Warning  Failed     28s               kubelet            Error: failed to start container "mypod": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/c84a8d278dc2f131daf9f322d26ff8c54d68cea8cd9c0ce209f68d7a9b677b3c/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf" caused: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/34af5138f14d192ade7e53211476943ea82cd2c8186d69ca79a3adf2abbc0978/merged/etc/resolv.conf: read-only file system: unknown
  Warning  BackOff    24s               kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulling    9s (x3 over 34s)  kubelet            Pulling image "nginx"
  Normal   Created    7s (x3 over 32s)  kubelet            Created container mypod
  Normal   Pulled     7s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 2.73055072s
  Warning  Failed     6s                kubelet            Error: failed to start container "mypod": Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/c84a8d278dc2f131daf9f322d26ff8c54d68cea8cd9c0ce209f68d7a9b677b3c/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf" caused: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/01bfa6b2c35d5eb12ad7ad204a5acc58688c1e04d9b5891382e48c26d2e7077f/merged/etc/resolv.conf: read-only file system: unknown
```

Why does this fail?  Is it possible to have a secret mounted at the `/etc` level instead of `/etc/something` level?  If yes, how can I achieve that?  Thank you so much!

Comment: It fails because your container now does not have all the other vital `/etc` paths. Also check `subPath` property of a `volumeMounts`

Comment: That's strange.  The initial configuration works fine.

Comment: "The initial configuration works fine" --- it works fine because it does not wipe `/etc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
volumeMounts:
- name: myval
  mountPath: /etc
  readOnly: true
```

Instead of /etc **directory**, try mount as a single file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: nginx
type: Opaque
stringData:
  val1: asdf
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumeMounts:
    - name: myval
      mountPath: /etc/myval
      subPath: myval
  volumes:
  - name: myval
    secret:
      secretName: nginx
      items:
      - key: val1
        path: myval
...
```

Comment: This works! Thanks. So specifying `subPath` causes it to mount as a single file?  When I comment out the `items` portion of `myval` in `volumes` and apply the file, the pod can be created.  However using `cat` at `/etc/myval` shows it to be an empty folder.  Removing `subPath` and redoing it shows 2 files, `val1` and `val2`.